# need a user defind function to concatinate cell values in excel

Tags: excel, user-defined-functions, vba

Can any once can help me to create a function to concatenate 1000 cell’s to a single cell by passing the cell range, tried many user defined functions, for less number of rows it will working fine but coming for 1000 rows it’s missing some rows.
Thanks in advance for all the help!

Comment: show us please, what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

If this is working for a smaller number of rows I would suspect you are running into the limit of a cell:

Length of cell contents (text)  32,767 characters. Only 1,024 display in a cell; all 32,767 display in the formula bar.

Taken from

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP005199291.aspx